# Pellet-2.3 packages missing?

Tags: jena, owl, pellet

I've downloaded and install `Pellet-2.3` from [here](http://clarkparsia.com/pellet/download) (containing Pellet and Jena and many others plug-ins). Within an Eclipse Jena project It is impossible for me to acces following packages.

```
import org.mindswap.pellet.jena.ModelReader;
import org.mindswap.pellet.jena.OWLReasoner;
```

Even when **build path** have been set. It really seems thats thoses file `ModelReader.class` and `OWLReasoner.class` are miss.

Did someone know how to deal with this ?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question was already answered [here](http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/19329/did-pellet-23-implement-modelreader-and-owlreasoner-for-jena-api).